# Fix version issues of Python on CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos, python, version, version-control

I installed python 2.7.9 under a users directory on centOS 6.6 and then installed virtualenv and set up a project. Now the issue is, the system is using python 2.7.9 while the virtual environment is using Python 2.6.6 (the systems original python version).

I need version 2.7.9 to work with an API that requires 2.7.9, so I need to change this around to the system using 2.6.6 again and my virtual environment using 2.7.9.

Answer (score 0):

To use the api that requires python 2.7, go to the user directory where your virtual environment is set up and run `bin/activate`. Now, you can install the api and use virtualised python.
Your shell prompt will become like,

```
(virt1)user@host:~$
```

Once you are done with the work, to go back to the system python, again run, `deactivate`. Now, you will be out of the virt-env. your shell prompt will become like,

```
user@host:~$
```

Comment: Thanks, that I have down already since that's how I was able to get the different versions running on the OS and also on the virtual environment.